# How can I convert my existing C# Windows Desktop Form project in the easiest way to a Windows service. (The form UI part I want to scrap completely)

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-services, desktop-application

I am a beginner and have programmed a C# Windows Desktop form app with Visual Studio 2022. The app is collecting data from remote machines in scheduled plan (automaticaly every 2 hours, without needing a manuel trigger)

The user interface was more for

1. making some adjustments and fine tunings and
2. showing diagnostic screens like charts for the developing phase of the new concept.

Actually the concept is fine and there is no need for the User interface parts of the project.

Now I want to convert my project to a windows service. As I am doing this for the first time I don't know how should I do this in the easiest way.

Should I create a new Windows Service Project and design the project from beginning or is there an easier way to make the conversion?

Comment: If that windows service is going to spend most of its time doing absolutely nothing outside of those 2 hour intervals, you might want to consider running a console application via windows scheduled tasks instead.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Hello, one question regardingly: Is it possible to convert my desktop form app to console application directly from the project properties? Will that work? Or should I design the consol app new?

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to run a desktop application regularly, you should try `Task Scheduler` which is provided by Microsoft in windows management tools.
2. Windows service usually run a console/web application which need long time running. Desktop application does not fit that.
3. Converting an application to a windows service, you can try this project: https://github.com/winsw/winsw I use this tool parse my console/web application to windows service. maybe you can try and see if it works.

Comment: Hello, My problem why I cannot use the Task Scheduler is, that my app should run automaticaly even if there is no one logged in in the server. If our company server is restarted and nobody is logged in the windows form app is not started by the task scheduler

Comment: @Mdarende I know your problem, There is a way to set auto login when the server power on: `Win+R` then: `control userpasswords2`